# different images for horizontal and vertical border - CSS

Tags: asp.net, html, css, user-interface, border

I have two png images created by myself in corel-draw as shown below, 
1 horizontal and 1 vertical.

I want to do something like this, in css

```
.desiredSpan{
    border-top-image:horizontal.png
    border-bottom-image:horizontal.png
    border-left-image:vertical.png
    border-right-image:vertical.png
}
```

I have seen border-image property, but it uses the same image for vertical & horizontal border.
Although I don't mind using it if it can solve my problem.

[image]

[image: vertical]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, keep in mind that border-image not supported by Internet Explorer : http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image

Second, border-image can only be used with 1 image (so you need to combine them, I did it for you, here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/miKyw.png

Third, for the moment, only the "border-image" directive is supported by Chrome and Firefox... not "border-top-image" and others.

Fourth, here is the CSS to use in your example :

```
.bordered {
    width: 500px; // or what you want. 500px is the image width
    border-width: 20px;
    border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/miKyw.png) 20 stretch;
}
```

Last, here is an example I made for you, to see how to deal with border-image: http://codepen.io/ByScripts/pen/zHitp

Answer (score 1):

You've got all these selectors in CSS3:

```
border-image:
border-top-image
border-right-image
border-bottom-image
border-left-image

border-corner-image:
border-top-left-image
border-top-right-image
border-bottom-left-image
border-bottom-right-image
```

via http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/

Comment: Already tried help from that page. It doesn't work. event the borders shown on that page are not really borders, .. They are static images.

Comment: What about using browser hacks? Something lige: `-moz-border-image:url("/files/4127/border.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Old firefox */
    -webkit-border-image:url("/files/4127/border.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Safari */
    -o-border-image:url("/files/4127/border.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Opera */`

Answer (score 1):

Everything about the [CSS borders here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-border-20021107)

But, they don't work in IE I guess.Look here for the compatibility:

http://caniuse.com/#search=border